# Modify cell in a R DT::datatable based on previous row

Tags: r, datatable, callback, shiny

I have a shiny app where I would like to modify the data displayed and/or the attributes of a cell based on the value of the same cell in the previous row.

In my code I have formatted whole rows based on the value of data[0] in rowCallback.

```
output$result <- DT::renderDataTable(tabledata(),
    class = c('compact'),
    rownames = FALSE,
    server = FALSE,
    escape = TRUE,
    extensions = options = list(
                  rowCallback=JS("
                    function (row, data, index) {
                      var string=data[1], substring = 'sub total';
                     if (data[0]=='Grand Total') {
                       $(row).css('background-color', '#DEDEDE'), $(row).css('font-weight', 'bold') ;
                     }
                     else if (data[0].includes('sub total')) {
                       $(row).css('font-weight', 'bold');
                     }
                     }"
                   )
                  )
    )
```

Can I achieve a modification of the data[0] cell based on the value of the same cell in the previous row using one of the callback functions?

Comment: Not sure.. but you can try something with getting the index of a certain value.. and then put this index value -1 and set that attribute

Comment: Hi @zwep.... I've been thrashing around with the index of the row as passed to the rowCallback but can't quite get it.

Answer (score 2):

So I changed tack and used the following drawCallback call

```
drawCallback=JS(" function ( settings ) {
           var api = this.api();
           var mydata = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).data();
           var last=null;
           api.column(0,{page:'current'}).data().each( function ( value, index ) {
               if ( value == last) {
                   mydata[index][0] = ''
                   api.rows({ page: 'current' }).invalidate();
                   }
               last=value;
               });
            }"
            )
```

Comment: Any chance you can expand on this answer? Your original question is exactly what I want, but I'm not totally sure how this fixes it.